# Docker - Karaf image with Mongo Image

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, docker, docker-machine, karaf

I have created the karaf dockerfile from scratch and it works with my application. Now, the postgreSQL and the MongoDB containers need to be running on the same network as the karaf container for the final step. Essentially, what i have so far is three separate dockerfiles. And what i need is for them to be able to communicate with each other. How do i approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `docker network ls` command firstly, it will show the networks exist in the machine. 
Then run your `MongoDB` container and set `--net` param.

`docker run --net karaf_default mongo`

The mongo and karaf will be in the same network now. (you can check doc of `--link`)